# SQL CTE for looping case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having Membership table with below structure

```
GroupID  MemberType MemberID

   G1     user       U1
   G1     group      G2
   G2     user       U2
   G2     group      G3
   G3     group      G1
```

Here, my need is.. need to get Group Members by using GroupID..

For **Direct Members**, we can easily do it by using GroupID column in where query..

but to get also **Nested Members**, we need to execute this query recursively. For that I have used the following CTE Query.

```
;with cte as 
(
    select *, groupid as mastergroup,1 as level from mytable 
    union all       
    select t1.memberid, t1.membertype, null, cte.mastergroup, level+1
    from cte 
        inner join mytable t1
            on t1.groupid=cte.memberid
    where cte.membertype='group'
) 
select * from cte
where mastergroup='G1'
```

Nice. it is working fine if there is no looping between the nested groups. but In my case

I am having loop structure in this way...G1-->G2-->G3-->G1... so in this case, my query is running indefinitely in CTE looping.

Can any help me to resolve this case?.....Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Check this solutions it might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192945/sql-server-2005-recursive-query-with-loops-in-data-is-it-possible

Comment: Got solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192945/sql-server-2005-recursive-query-with-loops-in-data-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the solution below is acceptable for you as it doesn't completely resolve the looping problem in theory but in practice it should work.

It relies on the fact that you cannot have indefinitely looping recursion but you can limit it to some level - in my example below to 100. This means it will still go through loops but as long as the loops are not too long (total chain < 99), it will work fine and find all the members.

```
declare @mastergroup varchar(10) = 'G1'
declare @maxlevel int = 100

;with cte as 
(
    select groupid, memberid, membertype, 1 as level 
    from mytable1 
    where GroupID = @mastergroup

    union all     

    select t1.groupid, t1.memberid, t1.membertype, cte.level+1 as level
    from cte 
    inner join mytable1 t1
        on t1.groupid = cte.memberid
    and cte.level < @maxlevel
) 
select distinct groupid, memberid, membertype from cte
where MemberID <> @mastergroup
```

Comment: Hi @Szymon thanks for your answer... I got the solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192945/sql-server-2005-recursive-query-with-loops-in-data-is-it-possible