# Recursive CTE to update parent records through multiple levels

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Will a CTE use data that is updated as part of the CTE in the next recursion? I am trying to attempt this CTE because the performance of a similar UPDATE logic inside of a WHILE loop is not performing well and I was hoping that using the CTE would be more set based and perform better.

I am having trouble with a recursive CTE updating a table until the parent rows are all marked properly.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e276/4)

The SQL fiddle shows the table and basic CTE. Before even adding in any of the AND/OR or level logic, I cannot seem to get the CTE to climb the hierarchy and mark the parents as "met".

Here is the example table:

```
| LogicID   | ParentLogic   | Depth     | Type  | Description                           | Met   |
|---------  |-------------  |-------    |------ |-------------------------------------  |-----  |
| 1         | NULL          | NULL      | NULL  | Conditions All Met                    | 0     |
| 2         | 1             | 1         | AND   | The sky or ocean is blue              | 0     |
| 3         | 2             | 2         | OR    | The sky is blue                       | 0     |
| 4         | 2             | 2         | OR    | The ocean is blue                     | 1     |
| 5         | 1             | 1         | AND   | The grass is green or road is black   | 0     |
| 6         | 5             | 2         | OR    | The grass is green                    | 1     |
| 7         | 5             | 2         | OR    | The road is black                     | 0     |
| 8         | 1             | 1         | AND   | Birds, bugs or the 4 below            | 0     |
| 9         | 8             | 2         | OR    | There are birds                       | 0     |
| 10        | 8             | 2         | OR    | There are bugs                        | 0     |
| 11        | 8             | 2         | OR    | All 4 below                           | 0     |
| 12        | 11            | 3         | AND   | There are dogs                        | 1     |
| 13        | 11            | 3         | AND   | There are cats                        | 1     |
| 14        | 11            | 3         | AND   | There are people                      | 1     |
| 15        | 11            | 3         | AND   | There are chairs                      | 1     |
```

```
DROP TABLE MyLogic
CREATE TABLE MyLogic
    (
        LogicID int
        ,ParentLogic int
        ,Depth int
        ,Type varchar(4)
        ,Description varchar(35)
        ,Met int
    );

INSERT  INTO MyLogic
        ( LogicID, ParentLogic, Depth, Type, Description, Met )
VALUES
        ( 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Conditions All Met', 0 ),
        ( 2, 1, 1, 'AND', 'The sky or ocean is blue', 0 ),
        ( 3, 2, 2, 'OR', 'The sky is blue', 0 ),
        ( 4, 2, 2, 'OR', 'The ocean is blue', 1 ),
        ( 5, 1, 1, 'AND', 'The grass is green or road is black', 0 ),
        ( 6, 5, 2, 'OR', 'The grass is green', 1 ),
        ( 7, 5, 2, 'OR', 'The road is black', 0 ),
        ( 8, 1, 1, 'AND', 'Birds, bugs or the 4 below', 0 ),
        ( 9, 8, 2, 'OR', 'There are birds', 0 ),
        ( 10, 8, 2, 'OR', 'There are bugs', 0 ),
        ( 11, 8, 2, 'OR', 'All 4 below', 0 ),
        ( 12, 11, 3, 'AND', 'There are dogs', 1 ),
        ( 13, 11, 3, 'AND', 'There are cats', 1 ),
        ( 14, 11, 3, 'AND', 'There are people', 1 ),
        ( 15, 11, 3, 'AND', 'There are chairs', 1 )
```

This is just a sample of a much more complicated set of logic. Basically the idea is that I need each set of children to "rollup" to the parent using the logic in the table. The depth is variable but is likely to be 7 deep.

So, LogicID 12,13,14,15 are ANDed together and would then mark 11 as Met. Then 9,10,11 would be evaluated and if any (OR) then mark 8 as Met. And so on, until the top level parent LogicID 1 is either Met or not Met.

Can this be done with the CTE and if so can someone help me get it going?

EDIT::
Thanks for the help - as requested here is the update statement.

`DECLARE @maxdepth AS int = ( SELECT MAX (Depth) FROM MyLogic)   
DECLARE @counter AS int = 0

WHILE ( @counter < @maxdepth )
    BEGIN

        UPDATE
            UP
        SET 
            UP.Met = 
            --SELECT *,
            CASE 
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'AND' AND ORIG.Met = 0 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 2 THEN 0
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'AND' AND ORIG.Met = 0 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 1 THEN 0
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'AND' AND ORIG.Met = 1 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 2 THEN 0
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'AND' AND ORIG.Met = 1 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 1 THEN 1

            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'OR'  AND ORIG.Met = 1 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'OR'  AND ORIG.Met = 0 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 2 THEN 1
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'OR'  AND ORIG.Met = 1 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 2 THEN 1
            WHEN ORIG.Type = 'OR'  AND ORIG.Met = 0 AND COUNTS.CountMet = 1 THEN 0
            END
        FROM
            MyLogic UP
        INNER JOIN dbo.MyLogic ORIG
            ON UP.LogicID = ORIG.ParentLogic
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT
                        DIST.ParentLogic
                        ,COUNT(DISTINCT DIST.Met) AS CountMet
                    FROM
                        MyLogic DIST
                    GROUP BY
                        DIST.ParentLogic
                    ) COUNTS
            ON ORIG.ParentLogic = COUNTS.ParentLogic

        SET @counter = @counter + 1

    END`

Comment: Can you provide your current UPDATE/WHILE solution example?  I think it would be more fruitful to see if that can be optimized.

Comment: You may find this related answer instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8529569/116614.  My thought is the logic is beyond the scope of efficient set-based processing.  Download the data to another programming language, process the logic, then write the results back to the database.

Comment: for 1 level, is it always AND or always OR? Or is it possible to have a mix of AND/OR for 11 childs such as 12, 13, 14 with AND and 15 with OR? And why not use the parent Type (12-15 would be OR instead of AND)

Comment: There is no AND/OR mixing -at least not in the sense that I think you are asking. That would require logic with a parentheses and in that case I instead would make a "fake" parent of the group of ANDs to avoid that situation. It would look like this where I move the ANDs to a child set.

OR:      Sunny Days and Margaritas
......AND - Sunny Days
......AND -  Margaritas
OR:  Trip to Mexico

Comment: ok. but it does not seem logical to me to do a 12 AND 13 AND 14 AND 15 = 11 because the 4 of them have a AND. I thought it would be more logical to set in 11 how you will compute its child. I will look into it anyhow. Looks fun.

Comment: The logic is derived from a specification not always something I have control over. I can't refractor it and still have it always be close to the spec . I get what you are saying though. Sorry for the vagueness. The topic comes from proprietary work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will be able to accomplish your goal in this scenario with CTE. Every approach I tried with CTE hinges on being able to use `GROUP BY` in the recursive part of the CTE which is not allowed.

Here is an alternative that should speed up your UPDATE. It's still a bit iterative, but it seems to be a good bit faster in my quick testing owing mostly to more set-based approach and fewer joins needed. It should scale more efficiently as well than the current process.

```
DECLARE @D AS INT = ( SELECT MAX (Depth) FROM MyLogic)
WHILE @D > 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE P SET
        Met = C.Met
    FROM MyLogic P
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT

                ParentLogic,
                CASE
                    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'OR' THEN Met ELSE 0 END) > 0
                        OR SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'AND' THEN Met ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Met
            FROM MyLogic
            WHERE Depth = @D
            GROUP BY
                ParentLogic
        ) C -- Only update parents with children
            ON P.LogicID = C.ParentLogic
    WHERE COALESCE(P.Depth, 0) = @D - 1 -- Get next level up
    SET @D = @D - 1
END
SELECT * FROM MyLogic
```